# Is there any way through which I can force an hyperlink to open in browser only instead of app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a direct download generated of a file that is on google drive.Link to that file is:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1_kmh7bQmeLbgz8rsP4GaxWRBeJkzpo8g

The purpose of generating direct download link is to start download directly without opening file in google drive.

Whenever I open up this link in laptop/pc download is started directly but when this link is opened in smartphone having google drive app installed instead of starting download directly the link is opened in google drive.

Is there any way i can force the link to open up in browser only ?

Below attached is screenshot what it shows:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch to Javascript for me it works.

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = 'download';
link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    link.href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwuGm1VLQXLgTWNnd0pvbnBvTFk";
}, false);
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

```css
a {
    background: #69c;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: In pc or laptop the download is starting directly while i've opened this in smartphone it shows an option to user either to continue with browser or drive (app).
Can we force link such that it continues with browser only?

Comment: Have you tried the code I shared with you with your phone? 
for me it works.

Comment: yes I've tried that in my phone but it is giving me choice to either continue with browser or app

Comment: questions updated with screenshot kindly have a look

Comment: From there I'd say you have to look at your phone...
This link can help you: https://www.futura-sciences.com/tech/questions-reponses/android-android-modifier-application-defaut-action-3522/

If another person has a solution, I'll leave my place.

Comment: If this at least gives you the option, I think that's pretty good.